# is there any JavaScript code static analysis algorithm can use?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, static-analysis

I want apply static analysis to js code, to find specfic js function call chains.

For example, I have a `lib.js` file:

```js
// lib.js

const foo = {
    test() {
        console.log('test')
    }
};

module.exports = foo;
```

in another file `main.js`, I write some wrapper code, just like:

```js
// main.js

const bar = require('./lib.js');

function process (target) {
    for (m in bar) {
        target[m] = bar[m]
    }
}

const buzz = {};

process(buzz);

buzz.test();
```

when run `main.js`, absolutely `buzz.test()` will log `test` for `buzz.test` method has a reference to `foo.test` method. But how can I apply some static analysis strategy to this requirement:

> When a function call occurs in code, I want apply static analysis (code is not actually running in an runtime (browser / Node.js)) to know whether it call method on `foo` object (in `lib.js`)

I try to use js AST parser (eg. babel-parser) to transform js code to ast and try to transform my understanding of js code to ast analysis algorithm, but the result is not very decent.

is there any good algorithm to fulfill this requirement.

thx.

Comment: You could use Sinon: sinon.spy(object, "method") creates a spy that wraps the existing function object.method. The spy will behave exactly like the original method (including when used as a constructor), but you will have access to data about all calls. https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/spies/

Comment: I read the sinonjs document, it seems work when code runing in a runtime(browser / Node.js). but  what I need is applying static analysis to code without code running. anyway it's still a good suggestion. thx.

Comment: You can reduce this to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). Assume you have a simple main function like: `runCodeThatMightHaltOrNot(); foo()`. Then if you could use static analysis to decide if `foo` is run or not, you would have solved the halting problem, which is not possible. So, even though there are probably lots of special cases where static analysis could decide which functions will be called, it is not possible in general.